Materialized view log fast refresh memory management
I have a materialized view which is currently refreshing in complete mode (taking around 30 mins to refresh). I'm trying to optimize it by changing the refresh mode to fast. As the history data in the underlying tables won't change much.
My materialized view has 3 tables joined in below way:
T1 left join t2 left join t3

All these 3 tables are referred in multiple materialized views (which are refreshing in complete mode at different times in a day/weekly). I will not be changing the refresh modes for other materialized views as they are performing well.

Do I need to enable materialized view logs on all 3 tables?
Will left join work for a fast refresh?
How is the materialized view log purge configured, is it automatic or manual?
What will be frequency of purge?
Any other suggestions for improving the materialized view performance are welcome.


for most, you can answer yourself by reading the results of:
create table mv_capabilities_table (
   statement_id      varchar(30),
   mvowner           varchar(30),
   mvname            varchar(30),
   capability_name   varchar(30),
   possible          character(1),
   related_text      varchar(2000),
   related_num       number,
   msgno             integer,
   msgtxt            varchar(2000),
   seq               number
);


execute dbms_mview.explain_mview('SCHEMA.MVIEW_TO_ANALYZE') ;
select * from MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE ; 
--     truncate table MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE ; --before each run



Yes, you need MV Logs on all source tables.
You can use joins in a fast refresh, but you generally need to include the ROWID column from each source table in your MV query. Alias them something like t1.rowid t1_rowid, t2.rowid t2_rowid, etc. so you can include them all and tell them apart.
and 4. Log purge is automatic when a refresh takes place. When all MVs registered against the log have received a particular update, that individual update record is purged. If you only have one MV, then it should purge the log completely with each refresh.

